# Setting accessibility identifier programmatically on UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, automation, accessibility

The accessibility identifier is a developer generated ID for GUI objects, which can be used for automation tests.

A `UIBarButtonItem` does not implement `UIAccessibilityIdentification`. However is there a possibility that I can assign an accessibility identifier?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could subclass `UIBarButtonItem` and implement the `UIAccessibilityIdentification` protocol in that subclass, lets's say `BarButtonWithAccesibility`.

In `BarButtonWithAccesibility.h`:

```
@interface BarButtonWithAccesibility : UIBarButtonItem<UIAccessibilityIdentification>

@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *accessibilityIdentifier NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
```

The only (strict) requirement for adhering to this protocol is defining the `accessibilityIdentifier` property.

Now in your view controller, let's say in `viewDidLoad`, you could set up a UIToolbar and add your subclassed UIBarButtonItem:

```
#import "BarButtonWithAccesibility.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

    BarButtonWithAccesibility *myBarButton = [[BarButtonWithAccesibility alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)];
    myBarButton.accessibilityIdentifier = @"I am a test button!";

    toolbar.items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myBarButton, nil];
    [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
}
```

And within the `buttonPressed:` you could verify that you have access to the `accessibilityIdentifier`:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[BarButtonWithAccesibility class]]) {
        BarButtonWithAccesibility *theButton = (BarButtonWithAccesibility *)sender;
        NSLog(@"My accesibility identifier is: %@", theButton.accessibilityIdentifier);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks like iOS 8 fixed the issue, and `accessibilityIdentifier` can now also be used with `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: @fabb - Table view cells are not showing in scripts in iOS 8. Do u have any idea

Comment: It's not working with _Appium Inspector_. It shows 'BarButtonWithAccesibility' (and 'UIBarButtonItem') as 'UIAButton' and it sets name as icon file name.

Answer (score 5):

As of iOS 5 you can do it like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init...;
btn.accessibilityLabel = @"Label";
```

Comment: Is the accessibility identifier the same as label?

Comment: not sure what you mean, but i'll give it a try: by default it's nil, you have to set it yourself.

Comment: u can use tag instead accessibility and also get object from tag.

Comment: The identifier is not the same as the label.  If I'm localizing the element then the label may change, but you'd want the identifier to stay the same - typical for cases where automated testing uses accessibility to identify UI elements.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `UIToolbar` created inside that if you want to create multiple `UIBarButtonItem` programatically then it can be accessed like that and set `accessibilityLabel` as well like that below:-

```
    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        UIBarButtonItem *infoButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"info" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered  target:self action:@selector(infoButtonClicked)];
        [self.customToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:infoButtonItem]];
//Here if you have muliple you can loop through it 
       UIView *view = (UIView*)[self.customToolBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    [view setAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"Test", @"")];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The subclassing `UIBarButtonItem` is a good solution. Depending on your needs, though, it may make more sense to simply assign the `accessibilityIdentifier` to the custom image of your `UIBarButtonItem`, assuming your `UIBarButtonItem` uses a custom image.